# getText() method in JavaFX 8 returning wrong value

Tags: javafx-8

I am trying to use getText() method to retrieve value of Java text field in myapplication instead of getting anull value I am getting

Output

```
 valueofTextFields= TextField@137095f8[styleClass=text-input text-field]
```

Code:

```
   TextField srcSchNameTextField = new TextField ();
   System.out.println("valueofTextFields= "+srcSchNameTextField);
```

I am not getting why I am getting a not null value without setting any value to this textfield. I am new to JAVA.Please help me to solve this issue

Comment: where you used `getText()` in the above code?

Comment: You are initializing a `TextField` object with `new`. You are not assigning any value to it. And when you are printing `srcSchNameTextField` its printing the object reference...

Comment: Thanks Anoop it worked for me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code example should look something like this:

```
    TextField srcSchNameTextField = new TextField ();
    srcSchNameTextField.setText("Some textfield content");
    System.out.println("valueofTextFields= "+srcSchNameTextField.getText());
```